# if error encounting Vue js project with Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Developing Vue js SPA app with Laravel backend. But in my Vue js file I have following code segments

```
<tr v-for="(tag, i) in tags" :key="i" v-if="tags.length"> //error is here
    <td>{{tag.id}}</td>
    <td class="_table_name">{{tag.tagName}}</td>
    <td>{{tag.created_at}}</td>
    <td>
        <Button type="info" size="small" @click="showEditModal(tag, i)">Edit</Button>
        <Button type="error" size="small" @click="showDeletingModal(tag, i)" :loading="tag.isDeleting">Delete</Button>  
    </td>
</tr>
```

Among them first line of code
`v-if="tags.length"` is indicating  red error  line here and highlighting following error message in vs-code

> [vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for] This 'v-if' should be moved to the
> wrapper element.eslint-plugin-vue Conditionally renders the element
> based on the truthy-ness of the expression value.

**How can I fix this problem here?**

Comment: Please do have a read https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-use-v-if-with-v-for.html

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to check the length, if the length equals 0 then 0 `tr` elements are rendered. Therefore, if you want to use v-if you should use it on a parent element otherwise the if is redundant.

https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-use-v-if-with-v-for.html